# Assigning a variable based on existence of other variables in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, variables, conditional-statements, local, webistrano

I got the job to fix a webistrano installation and now I am stuck in the situation where I have a receipt wherein the following assignment broke after the update from ruby 1.8 to ruby 1.9.3

```
if defined? var_one != nil
  var_to_be_used = var_one
else
  $logger.info(var_one)
  var_to_be_used = var_two
end
```

I have made sure (by adding the above log-entries) that `var_one` and `var_two` hold the expected values.
For example when I expect `var_one` to hold the value I got following log:

> ** value in var_one
>   *** undefined local variable or method `var_two' for #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x000000032a6040>

The first case is never reached. The script always goes to the else case - even when `var_one` holds a string.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `var_to_be_used =  (defined? var_one) ? var_one : var_two`

Comment: that has the same effect

Comment: try `var_one.nil? ? var_two : var_one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with

```
var_to_be_used ||= var_one rescue var_to_be_used ||= var_two rescue nil
```

accessing via `var_one.nil?` caused `undefined local variable or method 'var_one'` again.